# Reading 1 bean from other bean defined in different xml file in different directory

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, persistence

How can we read one from other bean defined in a different xml file in a different directory. For example, if there is a bean defined in

src\main\resources\serviceconfig\org\project\core_spring\file1.xml

that needs to reference another bean defined in
src\main\java\org\project\core\commons\persistence_spring\file2.xml

Is there any way to reference it or to import the resources of file2.xml into file1.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the whole relative classpath as in

```
<import resource="\org\project\core\commons\persistence_spring\file2.xml" />
```

solved the issue for me.

Still haven't tried the answer given by Chao though. Would be great if that one works because entering relative path and importing some resource everytime I need to refer to it can be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `file2.xml` into `file1.xml`. Using

```
   <import resource="classpath:file2.xml" />
```

After importing you can use bean defined in `file2.xml` in `file1.xml`.

Comment: Would I have to define the path to file2.xml in web.xml as classpath?

Comment: When I tried using it, I got an error :- class path resource [file2.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist. Tried it after adding the classpath to web.xml.

Comment: @user1439090: It should be on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<context-param>` tag in web.xml to include multiple bean definition files in your application. You can refer to both contexts both on the classpath or in your web folder. and you will be able to use the beans defined in those files as if they were defined in one file.

For example:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/com/your-company/file1.xml
        /WEB-INF/file2.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```